# How to handle canceled request in vapor?

Tags: swift, post, vapor, cancellation

I am using Vapor on a mac server. The server makes lengthy computation so I need to allow the client to be able to cancel the computation.

On the client side, I have the following Javascript code to send a POST request and wait for the result:

```
async function doSomething(text) {
    controller = new AbortController()
    const response = await fetch("http://" + website + "/api/dosomething",
        {
            method: 'POST',
            signal: controller.signal,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ text: text })
        })
    const results = await response.json()
    return results
}
```

as well as a button to cancel the process:

```
async function cancelquery() {
    controller.abort()
}
```

This works fine on the client side, i.e., the client does no longer wait for the result when I click the Cancel button. However, I don't know how to catch the "abort" signal on the server side to stop the computation. Is there any external variable, method or event in Vapor that I could use to know that the client sent an Abort signal?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely not related to server-side since server  doesn't know if client still waiting for the response or not.

[Aborting an HTTP request. Server-side advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506413/aborting-an-http-request-server-side-advantage)

Here's similar question but not related to exactly Vapor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link brings two wrong answers that state that it is not possible to cancel a server-side process... Which are untrue, as there is at least one solution in Node.js by adding an even listener: ```signal.addEventListener('abort', () => { stopmyprocess() };```

Comment: It's wrong since abort event is only possible on the client side https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/abort_event

Comment: Show me the real example with some endpoint using Node.js

Comment: Node.js actually runs on the server. When the client fetch request sends a POST request with a signal controller, then the server starts to listen to this signal. Later, when the client sends the 'abort' event to the signal listener, then the server fires the method "stopmyprocess()".

Comment: It is clear that Node.js runs on the server. Give me the link on the example with signal and POST request for Node.js that you are describing.

Comment: Canceling a request in Javascript(client side) + Node.js(server side) is standard. I am surprised that Vapor does not offer this basic functionality... https://www.atatus.com/blog/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-node-js/

Comment: This article shows only how to cancel REQUESTS (including requests sent from node.js), not how to cancel any server RESPONSES.

Comment: yes indeed. I thought Node.js was handling responses, my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate submitting your 'fetch' to an `eventLoop` or `promise`, but keeping track of it by storing a pointer to it in a dictionary on an App Config Key and passing a key back to your client. You can then create a 'cancel' route that uses the key to retrieve this event loop and invokes `close()` on it.

I haven't played with doing this, but it seems a reasonable place to start. See [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/basics/async/?h=promise#promise). You can allow for normal termination by adding a `whenComplete` handler to remove the entry in your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes sense. However, it is hard to believe that canceling a process on the server should be that complicated in Vapor, as opposed to the one-line code in Node.js. Clicking "cancel" in one's browser to cancel a long query is so basic...

Comment: There are no such functionality in node.js. The only way to cancel somehow the response process is to send some unique ID with first long-request, store it on the server while doing response, and once client want to cancel the request send an additional request to cancel the first one.

Comment: @imike, isn't that what I put in my answer? Apart from the id being generated by vapor and sent back as a response to the initial 'fetch'.

Comment: you are right. I am now managing the one-query per session by using a global variable "shouldTerminate" on the server; adding a route /api/cancel to set its value to true, and checking the value regularly during the computation. Thanks!

Comment: If it is a 'global variable' in the Swift sense, then it won't be 'per session' but across all sessions - i.e. a second session doing the same task whilst the first is running will overwrite the first. You will need to use App config keys or session data. I can edit my answer to include an example if you like?

Comment: Yes @Nick that's what you answered, that's why I'm clarifying it in comments under your answer